# Не останавливается сборка Jenkins после вызова исполняемого файла из bash

Tags: bash, jenkins

Есть сборка Jenkins, которая клонирует репо [Janus](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway) собирает и запускает janus. После старта janus сборка не останавливается и просто висит пока процесс с Janus не умрет.
Запуск происходит так

```
/opt/janus/bin/janus > /opt/janus_log.txt &
```

Как надо правильно исполняемый файл вызвать, чтобы сборка не зависала до смерти процесса janus?

Comment: наверное `&` лишний, вам же там не фоновая задача нужна?

Comment: Ну просто проблема в том, что как раз мне нужно чтобы это фоном запустилось и не тормозило Jenkins. Потому что он как бы остается в подвешенном состоянии и выводит в лог сборки stderr еще.

Comment: Ну так оно и запускается в фоне... *"Потому что он как бы остается в подвешенном состоянии и выводит в лог сборки stderr еще."* - это предложение грамматически несогласованно.

Comment: Ну так это же вроде неблокирующий вызов или как-то так. Мне и нужно было чтобы оно запустилось как-то в фоне и отпустило Jenkins и сборка не висела.

Comment: Да, это неблокирующий вызов, он выполняется в фоне, и последующие команды продолжают выполнятся не дожидаясь завершения этой. Чем вы недовольны - непонятно...

Answer (score -1):

Сделал через systemd в итоге. Добавил janus как сервис просто и из скрипта просто теперь рестартую его.